# Finding differentials of functions $p,q,v$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given the following 2 equations, where $p$ and $q$ are implicit functions of $v$. $$p^2 + vpq+q^2-1=0\\p^2+q^2-v^2+3=0$$

I need to find the values of $\large{\frac{dp}{dv}}$ and $\large{\frac{dq}{dv}}$ at $(p,q,v) = (0,1,2)$. How do I go about finding out? I attempted by using the differentials method.

$$\begin{align*}
2p\,dp+vp\,dq+vq\,dp+pq\,dv+2q\,dq&=0\\
(2p+vq)\,dp+(2q+vp)\,dq&=-pq\,dv
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
2p\,dp+2q\,dq=2v\,dv
\end{align*}$$

Hence, at $(p,q,v)=(0,1,2)$,
$$\begin{align*}
2\,dq&=4\,dv\\
\frac{dq}{dv}&=2
\\\\2\,dp+2\,dq&=0
\end{align*}$$

How do I continue from here?

Also, with the answers, how do I find the change in $p$ if $v$ increases from $4$ to $4.01$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chain rule $$dp=\frac{dp}{dv}dv\qquad dq=\frac{dq}{dv}dv$$
By total differentitaion of first equation
$$2p\frac{dp}{dv}dv+dv\ p\ q+v\frac{dp}{dv}dv\ q+v\ p\frac{dq}{dv}dv+2q\frac{dq}{dv}dv=0$$
$$\left(2p\frac{dp}{dv}+p\ q+v\frac{dp}{dv} q+v\ p\frac{dq}{dv}+2q\frac{dq}{dv}\right)dv=0$$
which simplifies to
$$(2p+v\ q)\frac{dp}{dv}+(vp+2q)\frac{dq}{dv}+pq=0\qquad (1)$$
By total differentitaion of second equation
$$2p\frac{dp}{dv}dv+2q\frac{dq}{dv}dv-2v\ dv=0$$
$$\left(2p\frac{dp}{dv}+2q\frac{dq}{dv}-2v\right)dv=0$$
which simplifies to
$$2p\frac{dp}{dv}+2q\frac{dq}{dv}-2v=0\qquad (2)$$
When you solve equations of (1) and (2) you can find for $(p,q,v)=(0,1,2)$
$$\frac{dp}{dv}=\frac{p\ q^2+2q\ v+p\ v^2}{v(p^2-q^2)}=-2$$
$$\frac{dq}{dv}=\frac{q\ p^2+2p\ v+q\ v^2}{v(q^2-p^2)}=2$$

For your second question we can use $v=4\quad dv=0.1$
$$dp=\left(\frac{p\ q^2+2q\ v+p\ v^2}{v(p^2-q^2)}\right)dv=\left(\frac{p\ q^2+8q+16p}{4(p^2-q^2)}\right)0.1$$
which depends on p and q.